# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed `cuda-8.0` and `cudnn5.1` on `CentOS`. Then, when importing `tensorflow` (`python 3.6`), it gives the error as above.

I have already set symbol link as below in /etc/profile. Are there any guys who occurred this kind of problem?

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Also, what makes me confused is that, I run nvcc -V, it shows

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

However, when I run `./deviceQuery` in folder `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`, on `device 0: "Tesla M40"`, it shows

```
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 8.0

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = Tesla M40
```

Comment: Obviously the tensorflow you installed was built against CUDA 9

Comment: I have fixed this issue by changing install tensorflow with pip3 instead of anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of tensorflow using "pip3 list | grep tensorflow" If it is of version tensorflow-gpu (1.5.0) then the required cuda version is 9.0 and cuDNN v7.

Look into the following link for more details:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases

Tensorflow installation guide needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tensorflow 1.5.0 is precompiled to CUDA 9.0 (which is outdated; Sept 2017).

The newest CUDA version is CUDA 9.1 (Dec. 2017) and sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu will not work with the newest CUDA 9.1. There are two solutions to the problem:

1.) Install CUDA 9.0 next to CUDA 9.1 (this worked for me)

2.) Build Tensorflow by yourself from the git source code

Either way do not forget to add the PATH variables to your operating system, otherwise you receive the error message stated in the question from your python interpreter.